# How to batch process images in a directory to create teaser-like thumbnails

Tags: python, image-processing, jpeg

I would like to run a script that goes through the jpgs in a directory one by one, takes a small square clip of the center of the image (100x100 pixels, for instance), and saves that square in a second directory as a new image.

Speed of execution is of no concern. Just looking for a way to get this done painlessly, preferably without needing to install anything I don't already have, and with a tool or language I sometimes use (preferably Python or Javascript).

How would you go about such a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python script that does what you want. You need to install Pillow first using the command `pip install Pillow`:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def crop_center(image, width, height):
    img_width, img_height = image.size
    left = (img_width - width) // 2
    top = (img_height - height) // 2
    right = (img_width + width) // 2
    bottom = (img_height + height) // 2
    return image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

def process_images(input_dir, output_dir):
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)

    for filename in os.listdir(input_dir):
        if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
            input_path = os.path.join(input_dir, filename)
            output_path = os.path.join(output_dir, filename)
            with Image.open(input_path) as img:
                cropped_img = crop_center(img, 100, 100)
                cropped_img.save(output_path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_directory = "/path/to/input/directory"  # Update this to your input directory
    output_directory = "/path/to/output/directory"  # Update this to your output directory
    process_images(input_directory, output_directory)
```

the `process_images()` function runs through all the images in the given `input_dir` folder, applies the `crop_center()` function to each image and saves it to the given `output_dir` folder (if this folder doesn't exits, it's created).

You can change the size of the crop by modifying the `width` and `height` parameters passed to the `crop_center` function call (I've set them both at 100 as per your example).

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm.

Comment: @robert00 glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

I see you have tagged with `python`, but not `javascript` despite being willing to consider Javascript answers so I am not taking your tagging as firm requirements. You also want to avoid installing anything, but I do not know what you have installed. You also ask how I would do it, and what the most painless way is....

IMHO, the most painless way to do this is with **ImageMagick** which is available for free on macOS, Linux and Windows.

```
# make output directory
mkdir OUT

# crop 100x100 from centre of all JPEGs in current directory, saving result in OUT
magick mogrify -path OUT -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 *.jpg
```